# masm how do i use a symbolic name in a variable definition?

Tags: assembly, masm

in .data section i have defined:

```
MyString byte "This is my string",0h
```

but how can I set a variable equal to MyString??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to initialize a pointer variable to point to your string, or do you want to copy the content of the string to a different string buffer?

Off the top of my head, the former would be something like this:

```
mov [MyDwordVariable], offset MyString
```

The latter would be something like

```
mov ecx, offset MyString
mov edx, offset MyNewString
jmp @2
@1:
inc ecx
inc edx
@2:
mov al, [ecx]
test al, al
mov [edx], al
jnz @1
```